# Did the Doctor in fact kill the Time Lords?

Tags: doctor-who, time-lord, time-war

Ok so, in the season 1 episode *The Dalek* when the Doctor confronts the Dalek he says that he made them burn, then says that the Time Lords burned with them... so in killing the Daleks did he in fact kill his own entire race?

> Dalek: [scared] Keep back!
>
> The Doctor: [the Doctor confronts the Dalek] What for? What're you going to do to me? Because if you can't kill, then what are you good for... Dalek? What's the point of you? You're nothing! What are you doing here? What the hell are you here for?
>
> Dalek: I am waiting for orders.
>
> The Doctor: What does that mean?
>
> Dalek: I am a soldier, I was bred to receive orders.
>
> The Doctor: Well, you're never going to get any. Not ever.
>
> Dalek: I DEMAND ORDERS!
>
> The Doctor: Well they're never gonna *come*! Your race is dead! You all
>   burned, all of you. Ten million ships on fire. The entire Dalek race, wiped out in one second.
>
> Dalek: You lie!
>
> The Doctor: I watched it happen. I *made* it happen!
>
> Dalek: You destroyed us?
>
> The Doctor: [the Doctor walks away from the Dalek] I had no other choice.
>
> Dalek: And what of the Time Lords?
>
> The Doctor: [pause] Dead. They burnt with you. The end of the last great Time War. Everyone lost.

[source of quote](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0562988/quotes?item=qt0292888)

Comment: This is dealt with in ongoing story development - do you want spoilers?

Comment: I do not mind spoilers in the least!! @HorusKol

Comment: Supposedly the Doctor shoved the events of the Time War (and all of its protagonists, including his own people) into a time bubble, then cut if off from the rest of the universe. Later episodes contradicted that slightly. You'll probably want to watch 'The Sound of Drums', 'The End of Time' and the 50th Anniversary special to get a flavour of what happened.

Comment: I will! @Valorum The question was just bugging me though :) so I asked! Curiosity is a curse sometimes!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Major spoilers below!

The Doctor did honestly believe that he destroyed Gallifrey and the Timelords. In addition to the example you gave, he says it all few times over the rest of the series.

> **House:** *Why should it matter to me in which room you die? I can kill you just as easily here as anywhere. Fear me. I've killed hundreds of Time Lords.*
>
> **The Doctor:** *Fear me. I've killed all of them.*
>
> <sub><sup>[The Doctor's Wife](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Doctor%27s_Wife)</sup></sub>

However, the 50th Anniversary episode *The Day of the Doctor* reveals that the Doctor was able to save Gallifrey in a pocket universe. Because of timey wimey rules, only the 11th and subsequent Doctors remembered, causing the previous regenerations  and the world at large to believe Gallifrey was destroyed.

> **10th Doctor**: You're not actually suggesting that we change our own personal history?
>
> **11th Doctor**: We change history all the time. I'm suggesting far worse.
>
> **War Doctor**: What, exactly?
>
> **DOCTOR 11**: Gentlemen, I have had four hundred years to think about this. I've changed my mind.

Comment: Okokok! So he first kills them all to kill the Daleks but then thinks about it for a long long time, hopes back in all his many incarnations and saves the planet this time round? Have I got that right?

Comment: @Rincewind Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Oo... 0o0 gotta start watching faster!